# Python For Loop - Question about second loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am just starting to learn how to code in python and I am trying to get around understanding the following code:

```
import numpy as np
n=4 
matrix=np.zeros((n,n))  
for j in range (0,n):
  for i in range (n-1,n-j-2,-1):  
      matrix[i,j]=2*n-i-j-1 
print (matrix)
```

I would greatly appreciate if  someone could please help me understand  how each line executes and how  the code is revaluated with the loop. Especially how can I interpret the  second "for" loop regarding "i"
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily remove the matrix stuff, add a few print statements, and the code itself will tell you how the loops work!

```
n=4
for j in range (0,n):
    for i in range (n-1,n-j-2,-1):
        print(j, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if StackOverflow is the right platform for explaining the code. Anyways...

I changed the inner for loop to make it easy to understand

```
import numpy as np
n=4
```

## Create an n*n matrix

```
matrix=np.zeros((n,n))
```

## For each column in matrix

```
for j in range (0,n):
```

## For each row in jth column, but from n-j-1 to n-1

NOTE: 
In the original example, `-1` at the end indicates reverse order. I reversed the loop order and removed the `-1` at the end, to produce the same output. Please check to confirm

n-j-1 : This should be understood by examples. For `j==0` the value is `n-1` -> Last row.
For the last column `j==n-1`, the value is 0 -> First row. So for each column, starting from the last row, we proceed diagonally upward to the first row.

Simply a logic/equation to move diagonally upward.

NOTE: This is only the starting point for each column.

n - 1 : Last row (though the second number is n, the call `range(0, x)` or `range (x)` expands from `0` to `x - 1`. Much like array indexing)

```
    for i in range (n-j-1, n):
        matrix[i,j]=2*n-i-j-1 

print (matrix)
```